# Detect if model has been added as foreign key to some other model

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have some model instance A1 and existing models B1 and B2 have A1 as a foreign key field fk. Is there a way for the model instance A1 to know that another newly created model instance B3 has assigned it as it fk field (without having to set some kind of counter every time a model B uses A1 as its fk and tracking the counter changes)?

Ultimately, I'd like behavior similar to how users are notified of new answer or comment (say model B instance) when other users post to their questions (say model A instance).

Any advice on doing this efficiently would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a django post save signal

When any entry is save in models then the post save signal is execute you can find out the object has fk or not in post save signal.

Refer the following code.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class YourModel(models.Model):
    # ... fields here

# method for fk is assigned or not
@receiver(post_save, sender=YourModel)
def signal_name(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     if instance.fk:
         # Do your stuff
```

For more details refer [django signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/)

May be this helps you to find out the fk is assigned or not.